# JS function seems like does not get called

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a array with only one element (eventually I will expand the array for sure). At the very beginning, the element in the array is popped out, then the program finds that the element matches with "F2", **then a ball shows up.**  However, the ball does not shows up. I am concerned about my js code since I sort of use JS and jQuery together. Even though I can consider jQuery as the library of the JS, I am not sure if it is the issue here. The way that I debug JS code is to throw a bunch of `alert()` and try to find to which line `alert()` does not get called so I know there is a problem, but once again, I am not sure if it is the best to do it since there is no IDE in JS.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var notes = ["F2"];
  if($("#" + notes.pop()).innerHTML == "F2") {
    $("#F2").addClass("shown")
  } else {
    $("#F2").removeClass("shown");
  }
});
```

```css
#F2 {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: #ccc;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.not_shown {
  display: none;
}

.shown {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div id="ball">
  <div id="F2" class="not_shown"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: In your `if` condition, you are getting all element with tag name `F2`. Change `$(notes.pop())` to `$('#' + notes.pop())`

Comment: Thank you.  It is definitely the issue but with it fixed, there is still something wrong.

Comment: @vkosyj what exactly are you wanting your code to do?

Comment: @kevin628 If everything works well, then there should be a ball showing up.

Comment: @vkosyj I'm slightly confused as to why you're doing the whole `.innerHTML == 'F2'` bit. It won't be true since the element has no content. So your ball won't show up.

Comment: @vkosyj This if-statement `if($('#' + notes.pop()).innerHTML == 'F2')` is only true if the this html looks like this: `<div id = "F2" class = "not_shown">F2</div>`.  The `innerHTML` bit looking at the insides of the div, which in your code is empty.

Comment: Oh i see. i tried to pop out the only element, which is "F2" in the notes, then compares the value with "F2".

Comment: @kevin628 I tried to change the code to this "var notes = ["F2"];
 if($('#'+ notes.pop()).val() == 'F2') {   " but it still does not work.  how do I just compare the value?

Comment: @vkosyj what values do you want to compare?  How about this-- using the code in your question, change the `F2` div from `<div id="F2" class="not_shown"></div>` to `<div id="F2" class="not_shown">F2</div>` and refresh your browser so the code is executed again.  This might help you understand better what is going on.

Comment: @kevin628 Thank you kevin. It seems like that the ball and "F2" have to show up together.  Actually I just want the ball the show up.  I might have to redesign the project.  Thank you Kevin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to add content to the `div`, or to compare with the div contents. Since you're selecting by the ID, go ahead and compare the ID.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var notes = ['F2'],
      $el;

    // When selecting an element with jQuery, do it just once and
    // then reference it as much as you want
    $el = $('#' + notes.pop());

    // Use strict comparison unless you have an excellent reason not to (rare)
    if($el.get(0).id === 'F2') { // Just compare the ID, not sure why we need to even look at the content here
        $el.addClass('shown');
    } else {
        $el.removeClass('shown');
    }
});
```

As for debugging, you should be using the browser DevTools to step through the code. This way you can inspect values at specific points of execution, makes for easier debugging.

Edit: [Fiddle with working code](https://jsfiddle.net/ejfre0od/)

Comment: @vkosyj My fault for posting untested code :) Fixed it, should work now.

Comment: @godrzero Thank you again. Appreciate it.

Comment: One last question.  When i change part of the code to ""var c = note.pop();  $el = $('#' + c);", the code fails to perform.  Do you know what is the issue?  Thank you.

Comment: @vkosyj Any errors in the JS console? I'd highly recommend using the browser devtools. Add a breakpoint where you're doing `notes.pop()` and step through the code until you find the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I see few issues in the code.

First `$('#' + notes.pop()).innerHTML` is not correct. it should be `$('#' + notes.pop()).html()`.

Second there is no text `F2` in the `div`. So `($('#' + notes.pop()).html() == 'F2')` will fail always.

I modified it slightly.

```css
#F2 {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: #ccc;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.not_shown {
  display: none;
}
.shown {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="code.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="code_js.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="ball">
    <div id="F2" class="not_shown">F2</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var notes = ["F2"];
    debugger;
    if ($('#' + notes.pop()).html() == 'F2') {
      $('#F2').addClass('shown')
    } else {
      $('#F2').removeClass('shown');
    }

  });
</script>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on why using `.innerHTML` is incorrect please?

Comment: Is there a way to hide F2 after I run it since I just want a ball to show up.  Thank you.

Comment: @godfrzero $('#F2')  will return jQuery object for which I bilieve innerHTML is undefined. If you try $('#F2')[0].innerHTML it will work.

Answer (score 2):

From your question i understood that you want to pop the array element and compare it with "F2". If it matches then you want to change the div class.

Below is the corrected javascript code to achieve this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var notes = ["F2"];
  if(notes.pop() === 'F2') {
    $('#F2').addClass('shown')
  } else {
    $('#F2').removeClass('shown');
  }
});
```

You can find the working example at http://jsbin.com/nomavedamo/edit?html,css,js,output

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var notes = ["F2"];
    if($('#' + notes.pop()).innerHTML == 'F2') {
        $('#F2').addClass('shown')
    } else {
        $('#F2').removeClass('shown');
    }

});
```

i think u miss the # in the selector

Comment: Thank you.  It is definitely the issue but with it fixed, there is still something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You misunderstanded the useage of 'innerHTML'.So you can try this.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var notes = ["F2"];
    if($('#' + notes.pop()).length) {
        $('#F2').addClass('shown')
    } else {
        $('#F2').removeClass('shown');
    }

});
```

By the way, it's better to use something just like chrome dev tools to debug js, such as setting break point and so on. :）

Comment: the usage of innerHTML. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML